# Texture Sampler IDs not mapping to Texture Units

Tags: opengl, textures, soil

I'm attempting to use 3 textures on a model. I'm loading the images using SOIL and binding them to texture units 1, 2, and 3. But for some reason when I bind samplers 1, 2, and 3 to my shader, 1 produces the image bound to `GL_TEXTURE2` while 2 and 3 produce the image bound to `GL_TEXTURE3`. Am I missing something simple here?

Definitions:

```
GLenum baseTextureUnitID = GL_TEXTURE1;
GLenum filterTextureUnitID = GL_TEXTURE2;
GLenum accentTextureUnitID = GL_TEXTURE3;
GLuint baseTextureSamplerValue = 1;
GLuint filterTextureSamplerValue = 2;
GLuint accentTextureSamplerValue = 3;
```

Loading Images:

```
baseTextureID = SOIL_load_OGL_texture(baseImageFile,
    SOIL_LOAD_AUTO, SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID, SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y);
glActiveTexture(baseTextureUnitID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, baseTextureID);

filterTextureID = SOIL_load_OGL_texture(filterImageFile,
    SOIL_LOAD_AUTO, SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID, SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y);
glActiveTexture(filterTextureUnitID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, filterTextureID);

accentTextureID = SOIL_load_OGL_texture(accentImageFile,
    SOIL_LOAD_AUTO, SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID, SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y);
glActiveTexture(accentTextureUnitID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, accentTextureID);
```

Getting uniform locations:

```
baseTextureSamplerID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "baseTex");
filterTextureSamplerID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "filterTex");
accentTextureSamplerID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "accentTex");
```

Setting Uniforms:

```
glUniform1i(baseTextureSamplerID, baseTextureSamplerValue);
glUniform1i(filterTextureSamplerID, filterTextureSamplerValue);
glUniform1i(accentTextureSamplerID, accentTextureSamplerValue);
```

Now if I sample from baseTex I get the filter Image, while the filterTex and accentTex samplers result in the accent image

Comment: Do you call `glUseProgram` before `glUniform1i`? Also in OpenGL 4.4+ it is much easier to use `layout(binding=X)` in the shaders and the `glBindTextures` function in the code.

Comment: @ybungalobill I'm using 3.3 I should have specified. And I was not calling use program first, switching them made no changes though, I'm going to get some screen shot examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with the order of calls when you load the textures. `SOIL_load_OGL_texture()` will change your current texture bindings. It has to, since it needs to bind the newly created texture so that it can load data into it.

Just picture what happens in this sequence of your code:

```
glActiveTexture(baseTextureUnitID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, baseTextureID);
```

At this point, `baseTextureID` is bound to the intended texture unit. But the next line is:

```
filterTextureID = SOIL_load_OGL_texture(filterImageFile, ...);
```

Inside this call, the newly created texture will be bound to the current texture unit, which is the one you were planning to use for the base texture. This is the reason you have the wrong textures bound at the end of loading all the textures.

Fixing this is easy. Simply change the order of the calls in your image loading code to first load all the textures, and then establish all the bindings:

```
baseTextureID = SOIL_load_OGL_texture(baseImageFile,
    SOIL_LOAD_AUTO, SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID, SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y);
filterTextureID = SOIL_load_OGL_texture(filterImageFile,
    SOIL_LOAD_AUTO, SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID, SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y);
accentTextureID = SOIL_load_OGL_texture(accentImageFile,
    SOIL_LOAD_AUTO, SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID, SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y);

glActiveTexture(baseTextureUnitID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, baseTextureID);

glActiveTexture(filterTextureUnitID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, filterTextureID);

glActiveTexture(accentTextureUnitID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, accentTextureID);
```

Answer (score -2):

I've found the solution to this issue. When using multiple textures as I am, you have to activate the texture unit, and bind the texture again before calling `glUniform1i` for the sampler.

When setting uniforms, the correct format is:

```
glActiveTexture(baseTextureUnitID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, baseTextureID);
glUniform1i(baseTextureSamplerID, baseTextureSamplerValue);

glActiveTexture(filterTextureUnitID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, filterTextureID);
glUniform1i(filterTextureSamplerID, filterTextureSamplerValue);

glActiveTexture(accentTextureUnitID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, accentTextureID);
glUniform1i(accentTextureSamplerID, accentTextureSamplerValue);
```

Comment: No, this is just not true. The bindings are totally independent of when you set the uniform values. All what matters is the state of the texture units and the program uniforms as they are set at the time of the draw call. It is still unclear what is wrong in your original code, but this is not the solution.

Comment: To second derhass: this is not true. If this solved your problem, all that means is that you messed up the state somewhere, and because you did not post coherent working code we can't point out where exactly you did.

Comment: This is a solution. It isn't optimal because it continuously changes the texture. But it works. The accepted solution is better and provides actual reasoning.